# how to print or echo array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$tiger = array ("orange", "white");
$cat = array ("black", "white", "brown");
$fruit = array ("purple", "red", "green", "brown");
?>
```

How to output something like :

```
orange : tiger
white  : tiger + cat
black  : cat
brown  : cat + fruit
purple : fruit
```

Comment: Why not `print_r` or `var_dump`?

Comment: I think a little scope here would help. 1st question - what are you trying to achieve? 2nd question - are there just these 3 arrays to consider, or could there be any number?

Comment: 1st answer - i want to loop through all 3 different array variables to find which array variable has the element of "orange".

2nd answer - there are only 17 arrays, they are fixed, won't be less and won't be more. Only 17.

Comment: It would be better if you keep the data structure like - `$array =  array('tiger' => array('orange', 'white'), 'cat' => array('black', 'white', 'brown'))`.

Comment: If there are 17 arrays, they all should be in a bigger 2-d array. Just like in @JoshuaBurns code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little fun with arrays:

```
$arrays = compact('tiger', 'cat', 'fruit');
$values = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arrays));

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $found = array();
    foreach ($arrays as $name => $bag) {
        if (in_array($value, $bag)) {
            $found[] = $name;
        }
    }
    echo "$value: ".implode(", ", $found)."\n";
}
```

You can trivially extend this to any number of arrays by modifying the first line.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/1cp7E1)**.

Comment: thank you very much. It works perfectly. I learn a new thing `array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arrays));` from u today. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears you're interested in taking the color of various objects, and switching around the association so color reflect objects, rather than the other way around.

Here is one approach which works with your scenario:

```
<?php
// The objects we wish to extract colors for
$subjects = array(
  'tiger' => array ("orange", "white"),
  'cat' => array ("black", "white", "brown"),
  'fruit' => array ("purple", "red", "green", "brown")
);

// The array we will push colors to as keys, and objects to as values
$consolidated = array();

// Iterate over each object
foreach($subjects as $subject => $colors) {
  // Iterate over each color in the object
  foreach($colors as $color) {
    $consolidated[$color][] = $subject;
  }
}

// Print out results.
foreach($consolidated as $subject => $contents) {
  print $subject . ' : ' . implode(' + ', $contents) . "<br />\n";
}
```

The above outputs:

```
orange : tiger
white : tiger + cat
black : cat
brown : cat + fruit
purple : fruit
red : fruit
green : fruit
```